# Why does my Button look like it's from 1990?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, button

I'm writing a Windows GUI app and I have come on the need to have a normal button.

I am using this code to generate the button:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    NULL,
    "BUTTON",
    "Button",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    60, 25,
    parentHwnd, NULL,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

I want the button to look like this (Ignore the background colour):

[image: Good button]

But it ends up looking like this:
[image: Bad button]
I think I'm missing a style or something. What can I do to make it look like the first button?

Comment: You forgot the manifest.

Comment: @Ignacio, I am using Visual Studio, but my project is set to be a Console App. Would it work normally if I had made it a Win32 app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Normal looking button with c++ / win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475021/normal-looking-button-with-c-win32)

Comment: Doesn't matter what type of app it is, as long as it has a manifest.

Comment: @Ignacio Yes, I'm asking if the Win32 project settings have it set to generate a manifest automatically. I'd rather not do it by hand so I am wondering what settings I can use in VS to get it to do it for me.

Comment: @John Zane I don't think you want a console app. You don't want a console I would imagine. You want a plain Win32 app with no MFC etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Normal looking button with c++ / win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475021/normal-looking-button-with-c-win32)

Comment: I followed the suggestion in the answer below the accepted answer in that link and the button still looks bad.

Comment: Actually, I edit the manifest and compile, and then VS says "This file has been modified, do you want to reload it in the editor?" I click yes, and it returns to the way it was before I compiled, without the right dependency. How do I fix this?