# How can I add resources into my D executable? How to embed a manifest?

Tags: winapi, button, resources, manifest, d

I try to do some gui programming in D using the WinAPI. My problem is that buttons look ugly as in [the question another user asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486663/why-does-my-button-look-like-its-from-1990) In order to solve that I want to embed a manifest into my D application. As soon as I can include resources into my executable, I should also be able to add a manifest by hand according to [this Microsoft documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

So my question is: How can I include a resource into my D application on Visual Studio? Is it even possible to do that? If not, are there any other ways to make buttons look nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the integration of dmd into Visual Studio, but one way to achieve what you need is to add the compiled .res file to the list of files passed to dmd.exe. For example:

```
dmd.exe main.d manifest.res
```

I'd expect there be some way in your VS integration for you to add files to the dmd command that the IDE uses to compile your code.

Answer (score 2):

A little ugly, but it gets the job done, no manifests:

```
auto enableVisualStyles()
{
    TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH];
    dir[GetSystemDirectory(dir.ptr, dir.length)] = '\0';
    auto actCtx = ACTCTX(
        ACTCTX.sizeof, 0x0C, "shell32.dll", PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL,
        0, dir.ptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(124), null, HMODULE.init);
    ULONG_PTR ulpActivationCookie;
    return ActivateActCtx(CreateActCtx(actCtx), ulpActivationCookie);
}
```

Just make sure to call it once when your program starts.

Comment: Much better to include a manifest resource, as per the question.

Comment: @David If it works, that's fine for me. I'll give it a shot. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad What do you import to get the definitions of `ACTCTX` and other symbols like that? Are there some public complete winapi import modules for d?

Comment: Just wait until you run on a Windows version that doesn't have the resource you are looking for at ID 124 in shell32.dll. Then you'll regret your decision.

Comment: Yea, I just discovered that. Where does this magic number come from?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to link the resource to your exe, as you asked in the question? Why do you prefer to do it in this rather hacky, brittle way

Comment: I got the code to compile and run. However, the buttons look as before. :(

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: That's weird -- try stepping through the code to find out if `CreateActCtx` or `ActivateActCtx` is failing or not. It should be working correctly... did you make sure to call this before creating the windows?

Comment: Could someone explain what this code do? I faced with the same problem as described here 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0df2c4ef-adef-4ade-9e7e-8f90d9892b53/in-windows-10-icclinkclass-amp-wclink-classes-are-not-found?forum=windowsuidevelopment.

This is the only solution that works for me but I do not understand why...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about it actually being a "resources" but just need a data blob from a file embedded into the binary; take a look at "[import expressions](http://dlang.org/expression.html#ImportExpression)"

Comment: import expressions are really helpful in order to work around resources in general. For my particular problem, they don't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'VisualStyles' examples here: https://github.com/AndrejMitrovic/DWinProgramming/tree/master/Samples/Extra

Also the 'ThemedSimpleWakeUp' sample uses a resource file whereas 'ThemedWakeUp' dynamically enables visual styles.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at old project which used *dsss*:

```
$cat dsss.conf

[*]
buildflags+=-Jresources

version(Windows) {
    version(gui) {
        buildflags+= -L/SUBSYSTEM:windows:5
    } else {
        buildflags+= -L/SUBSYSTEM:console:5
    }
    buildflags+= -L/rc:.\resources\dwt
    ...
}
...
```

This should translate to something like:

```
dmd -JRES_PATH -L/rc:.\RES_PATH\MANIFEST_WHITHOUT_RES_EXT ...
```