# Win32 API button is looking new but it uses old fonts

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I use Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 Express and I'm like beginner with WinAPI. Just created some button with following code:

```
HWND g_hPrzycisk;
g_hPrzycisk = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Button Here",
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CENTER, 100, 100, 150, 30, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

And the button generates like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHOkF.jpg

Then, what's the problem? I wanted button to look more like windows 7 (use Segoe UI font or whatever is default one). I used the #prgma directive at the beginning, and searched web for some help. Got nothing. If it will help here's my #prgma

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

If anyone can help i'll be really thankful. If the question is duplicate - sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Normal looking button with c++ / win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475021/normal-looking-button-with-c-win32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WM_SETFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642.aspx) to assign the desired font to the button.

Answer (score 4):

To use the common controls v6 you also need to call `InitCommonControlsEx`